# Scraping the question and answer in separate rows like 1st row of A1 column contains que 1 1st row of A2 col catains answer for qes 1 and so on

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-shell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN1pw.png)I want to **scrape** the questionnaire from the below website https://www.sanfoundry.com/python-mcqs-basic-operators/

The format should be so that each question and answer are displayed in different columns. If the question contains only text without any html tag, that would be better.

I used scrapy to **scrape** this information, but the problem that I'm facing is that all the questions are appearing in a single row, and all the answers are appearing in another row.
I need the display to be: question 1 in one row and the corresponding  answer for this question in another row.

```
import scrapy

class QuestionSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "redbot"

    start_urls = ['https://www.sanfoundry.com/python-mcqs-basic-operators/']

    def parse(self, response):
        #Extracting the content using xpath selectors
        text = [
            ' '.join(
                line.strip() 
                for line in response.css("div > p").extract_first()
                if line.strip()
            ) 
            for p in response.xpath('//p')
        ]

        votes = [
            ' '.join(
                line.strip() 
                for line in response.css(".collapseomatic_content ::text") .extract_first()
                if line.strip()
            ) 
            for p in response.xpath('//div')
        ]
       
   
        #Give the extracted content row wise
        for item in zip(text,votes):
            #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            scraped_info ={
                'texts' : item[0],
                'vote' : item[1]   
            }

            #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_info
```

I need each question and corresponding answer in 2 different rows without html tag by using scrapy code. Please correct the code that I provided.

Comment: And i want to scrap all the corresponding  pages please help me i'm new to scrapy

Comment: first `yield text` to put all questions in one row, next `yield votes` to put all answers in another row.

Comment: The thing is i need each question in separate row with corresponding answer          like    question                     answer                                                                                                               
      1.what is python?       Python is scripting lang                                                     
      The next question in next row like this

Comment: `yield scraped_info` should give you question and answer in the same row - if you save it in csv. What do you get? Show it in question (not in comment) what you get and what you expect. Or Maybe you have to cut part of question or `replace("\n", other_char)` or `strip("\n")`

Comment: please find the output image in enter image description hereI tag at the starting @furas

Comment: Can you help me to solve this @ paul trmbrth

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(